# Simple Array Redirect

Tags: php, xml, arrays, youtube, simplexml

I'm trying to make a code that redirects a user to a random youtube video based off of the uploader. The script isn't loading at all and I don't know why. Here's the script

```
<?php
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USER/uploads?max-results=50';
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
$i=0;
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
      $watch = (string)$media->group->player->attributes()->url;
      $videoid = substr($watch, 31, -29);     
      $finalid = "\"$videoid\", ";
      $urls = array ($finalid);
      $url = $urls[array_rand($urls)]; 
      header("Location: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$url&list=UL"); 
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you done *any* testing? Are any of those function calls failing? Is the retrieved data correct? Have you turned error reporting on?

Comment: Yes I have. IF I echo final id, it works fine.

Comment: I've edited the formatting on your code to illustrate that your loop contains far more code than it should. Also, you cannot define an array in that way you seem to be attempting, it will contain nothing but a single string of several video IDs enclosed in quotes, separated by commas. Give me a moment to rewrite this.

Comment: Try commenting the header redirect and turning error_reporting to E_ALL. You most likely have output before the header call and php is set to fail if there is an error.

Comment: @Sammitch I was seeing the same thing, the last two lines of the loop should be moved outside the loop. However, the array setting wouldn't throw an error. It wouldn't work as desired, but not cause an error. It would just overwrite itself on each iteration. `$urls` should just be defined before the loop and append $videoid on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something more like this:

```
<?php
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USER/uploads?max-results=50';
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

// check the return value
if( $sxml === false ) { die('error retrieving XML data'); }

// declare an empty array
$video_ids = array();

// loop through returned data
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
    $watch = (string)$media->group->player->attributes()->url;
    // add each ID to the array
    $video_ids[] = substr($watch, 31, -29);
}

// check that there were some actual videos in that data
if( empty($video_ids) ) { die('No videos returned'); }

// pick
$url = $video_ids[array_rand($video_ids)]; 
//redirect
header("Location: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$url&list=UL");
```

Comment: I tried that and got the following errors [Here's a pastebin of it](http://pastebin.com/BtxwyH71)

Comment: Your pastebin suggests that 1. Your feed URL is incorrect. 2. You didn't keep the check on the return value. Additionally, $media->group->player->attributes()->url appears to be several different shades of incorrect as I've just attempted to run this code. Hint: `print_r($sxml)`

Comment: you lost me. I don't get it.